# How to return gridExtra as a plain plot object from a function

Tags: r, plot, gridextra

I have the following code, which aimed to make a tableGrob plot based on gridExtra and return it as object in a function

```
library(gridExtra)

myfunc <- function () {
  d <- head(iris, 3)
  g <- tableGrob(d)
  grid.draw(g)
}
```

But why when I called it this way

```
out_plot <- myfunc()
png(file='my_out_file.png', width=800, height=800)
out_plot
dev.off()
```

`out_plot` has nothing inside and `my_out_file.png` is not created.
What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You must call `grid.draw` within a device to create a file. Note how `out_plot <- myfunc()` already creates a plot in the active (in my case an RStudio) device. Your function returns `NULL` because that's what `grid.draw` returns, check `str(out_plot)`.

Thus, simply call your function inside the `png` device:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

myfunc <- function () {
  d <- head(iris, 3)
  g <- tableGrob(d)
  grid.draw(g)
}

png(file='my_out_file.png', width=800, height=800)
myfunc()
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can return the object after drawing it,

```
myfunc <- function () {
  d <- head(iris, 3)
  g <- tableGrob(d)
  grid.draw(g)
  invisible(g)
}
```